# Mobile Embedded PowerBI not resizing (height) as expected when switching between landscape and portrait

Tags: powerbi-embedded

When embedding a PowerBI report into a mobile app, switching the view from portrait to landscape results in an excess of grey space appearing below the report that wasn't there when the report initially loaded in portrait view. Switching back and forth between landscape and portrait does not restore the original/appropriate height inside the `iframe` it seems.

The report is loaded with the following configuration:

```
{
  type: 'report',
  embedUrl: 'https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed',
  layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
  customLayout: {
    displayOption: models.DisplayOption.FitToPage
  }
  ...
}
```

I would have expected the report to maintain the amount of space in the `iframe` needed to display report content and not have excess grey space remain/present. This seems like something that is being handled inside `reportEmbed.*.js`. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The scrollbar in the image gives a relative idea of how far down we are in the `iframe`.

UPDATE (19/07/18): This was tested on an iPhone running iOS 9.3.

[image: In app with excess grey space below report (w/ redacted text)]

Answer (score -1):

FitToPage option maintains the proportions of the page, and might still have gray shoulders remaining for iframes that don't hold the same ratio for height & width.

however, recent feature allows you to make the gray shoulders disappear:
https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Transparent-Background